# Not able to run Rococo/Westend chains with zombienet Mac binary

Tags: zombienet, parity-bridges-common, bridge

I am trying to test [Parity Bridge Common](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common) by spinning up local networks. I am following this document https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/parachains/runtimes/bridge-hubs/README.md.

I am using Mac and  trying to [Run Rococo/Westend chains with zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/parachains/runtimes/bridge-hubs/README.md#run-rococowestend-chains-with-zombienet) but it's not working.

I am using below command:

```
POLKADOT_BINARY_PATH=~/local_bridge_testing/bin/polkadot \
POLKADOT_PARACHAIN_BINARY_PATH=~/local_bridge_testing/bin/polkadot-parachain \
POLKADOT_PARACHAIN_BINARY_PATH_FOR_ASSET_HUB_ROCOCO=~/local_bridge_testing/bin/polkadot-parachain-asset-hub \
    ~/local_bridge_testing/bin/zombienet-macos --provider native spawn ./cumulus/zombienet/bridge-hubs/bridge_hub_rococo_local_network.toml
```

and getting

`zsh: permission denied: /Users/ayushkumarmishra/local_bridge_testing/bin/zombienet-macos`

I have replaced `zombienet-linux` with `zombienet-macos`. Please let me know if I am missing any step.

Comment: did you try `chmod +x ./zombienet-macos`?

Comment: @dastansam Thanks it works

Answer (score 0):

I tried `chmod +x ./zombienet-macos` and it worked